# How can I use gtag.js with anonymize IP to create a opt out?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I currently use this code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'xxx', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
</script>
```

and I use this button to create a cookie that makes a opt-out:

```
<a onclick="”alert(‘Google analytics wurde deaktiviert’); href="javascript:gaOptout();>Google Analytics deaktivieren</a>
```

but how can I use the new "gtag.js" to create this opt-out in the Analytics Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out) you can set window['ga-disable-GA_TRACKING_ID'] to "true" (where you'd replace GA_TRACKING_ID with your UAID) - this work basically as before.

Store the value set by the user in an cookie, read the cookie on subsequent pages and set the value accordingly on subsequent pages.

(Better yet, if your page code does not rely on an initialized Google Analytics object use serverside code to not load the GA code at all. That'S not always an option, though).